# Finding T for a linear transformation to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[image]

So this is the problem. I cannot seem to find a suitable T and was wondering if any insight could be shared.

I have that [[T(1)]c=[X(1) + Y(x-x^2) + Z(x^2)]=[1,2,0]T implying that X=1, Y=2, and Z=0.

Similarly, [[T(x)]c=[J(1) + K(x-x^2) + L(x^2)]=[-1,0,-1]T

Answer (score 1):

The matrix representation means that: $$T(1)=1+2(x-x^{2}+0x^{2}=-2x^{2}+2x+1$$ Can you compute $T(x)$ ? Remark then that any element of $P_{1}$ is a linear combination of $1$ and $x$.

Comment: T(x) would then equal -$x^2$ -1 right. but I am still confused how to construct a transformation T that satisfies [c[T]b]